# Javascript array filter with or clause

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object like this:

```
[
  {
    manufacturer: 'LG',
    diagonal: '32',
    resolution: '1080p'
  },
  {
    manufacturer: 'LG',
    diagonal: '24',
    resolution: '1080p'
  },
  {
    manufacturer: 'Samsung',
    diagonal: '32',
    resolution: '4k'
  },
  {
    manufacturer: 'Samsung',
    diagonal: '27',
    resolution: '1080p'
  },
]
```

If the filter has each property once `{'manufacturer':'LG', 'diagonal':'27'}` I can filter it like this `newarray = myarray.filter((item) => {return item['manufacturer']=='LG' && item['diagonal']=='32'})`

But how can I filter it, if the filter has each property multiple times?

```
{'manufacturer':'Samsung', 'manufacturer':'LG', 'diagonal':'32'}
```

I need something to work for bigger filters, not only for this particular case.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Object keys are unique. So I doubt you would have each property multiple times.

Comment: Lol that's not even possible. Json is key value pair. there can't be two keys with same name.

Comment: The example you created can never exist. A JSON object ```
{
  a : 1,
  a : 5
}
```
Is not valid. It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: If what you are trying to say is that 2 different objects have the same manufacturer. Then you can also filter based on multiple keys with &&. As filter function only needs a boolean return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
const myarray = [
  {
    manufacturer: 'LG',
    diagonal: '32',
    resolution: '1080p'
  },
  {
    manufacturer: 'LG',
    diagonal: '24',
    resolution: '1080p'
  },
  {
    manufacturer: 'Samsung',
    diagonal: '32',
    resolution: '4k'
  },
  {
    manufacturer: 'Samsung',
    diagonal: '27',
    resolution: '1080p'
  },
]



const newarray = myarray.filter((item) => {
  return ["LG", "Samsung"].some((val) => item.manufacturer === val) && item.diagonal=='32'
});
console.log(newarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to filter for multiple values? Something like :

```
newarray = myarray.filter((item) => {
    return ( item['manufacturer'] === 'LG' ||item['manufacturer'] === 'Samsung' ) 
             && item['diagonal'] === '32'} )
```

Or you could have a list of possible values and use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
const manufacturerToSearchFor = ['Samsung', 'LG'];

newarray = myarray.filter((item) => {
        return ( manufacturerToSearchFor.includes(item['manufacturer'])
                 && item['diagonal'] === '32'} )
```